# istio route rule error: "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value"

Tags: istio

I'm new to Istio and I'm going through some uses cases with my simple app.

I deployed 2 simple services on **minikube running on Windows 10 Pro with VirtualBox 5.2.6, with istio 0.6.0**

Version v1 of **service1** and v1 & v2 of **service2**.
service1 responds to /hello and service2 responds to /world. Everything working fine so far and both services are responsding and as of service2, the round robin is working.

Now I want to apply 2 route rules, one to route to v2 of service2 based on a header and the rest to v1 of service2, but when I try to do that I get an error:

```
Error: cannot parse proto message: YAML decoding error: destination:
  name: service2
match:
  request:
    headers:
      Foo: bar
precedence: 2
route:
- labels:
    version: v2
 json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]json.RawMessage
```

Please find below my app and route rules config.

**What's wrong with this config?**

Please notice that when I omit the "match" part it's OK, but of course this is not what I want.

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: service2-route
spec:
  destination:
    name: service2
  precedence: 2
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        Foo: bar
  route:
  - labels:
      version: v2
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: service2-default
spec:
  destination:
    name: service2
  precedence: 1
  route:
  - labels:
      version: v1
    weight: 100
```

and the my services deployment yaml:

```
###########################################################################
# Service 1
##########################################################################
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
  labels:
    app: service1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
  selector:
    app: service1
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service1
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service1
        image: myrepo/sampleapp-service1:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
###########################################################################
# Service 2
##########################################################################
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service2
  labels:
    app: service2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    name: http
  selector:
    app: service2
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service2-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service2
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service2
        image: myrepo/sampleapp-service2:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service2-v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service2
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service2
        image: myrepo/sampleapp-service2:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
---
###########################################################################
# Ingress resource (gateway)
##########################################################################
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /world
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 8081
---
```

Comment: What is the version of `istio` that you are using?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, its 0.6.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is pretty simple, you have to say how do you want to match your header. In your example, I can assume that you want an exact match, so the following syntax:

```
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        Foo: 
          exact: bar
```

[Here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#StringMatch) you can find more available options.
Also I would recommend to use quotes if your header value contains any special characters.